# object transformation with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, underscore.js

For whatever reason, I have quite a bit of difficulty when trying to transform objects and arrays.

The current data I have is stored in a mongodb collection and looks like this:

```
[{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "someName", "colorName" : "Pink"},
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "someName2", "colorName" : "RoyalBlue"},
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "aThirdOne", "colorName" : "Gold"},
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "oneMore", "colorName" : "LightGreen"}]
```

I need to get *either* the following two arrays, but would like to know how to get both.

```
[{ "value" : 1, "label" : "someName"},
{ "value" : 2, "label" : "someName2"},
{ "value" : 3, "label" : "aThirdOne"},
{ "value" : 4, "label" : "oneMore"]

[{1 : "someName"},
{2 : "someName2"},
{3 : "aThirdOne"},
{4 : "oneMore"}]
```

I know it is probably something with `_.map`, but I am not sure why I can't figure it out.  Please advise.

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to do it with `_.map` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need Underscore for this, it's just normal [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method usage (although Underscore also provides this method):

```js
var data = [{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "someName", "colorName" : "Pink"},
    { "_id" : 2, "name" : "someName2", "colorName" : "RoyalBlue"},
    { "_id" : 3, "name" : "aThirdOne", "colorName" : "Gold"},
    { "_id" : 4, "name" : "oneMore", "colorName" : "LightGreen"}];
    
var result = data.map(function(el, i) {
    return {value: el._id, label: el.name};
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Also note, that your second data structure doesn't make sense because it's irregular, so don't use it, it's not very convenient at all.

And here is corresponding Underscore version:

```
// Or Underscore version
var result = _.map(data, function(el) {
    return {value: el._id, label: el.name};
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! How could I do this without quotes around `value` and `label`? I realize I asked for quotes in my question, but curious how to do it without

Comment: You mean "_id"? Those quotes are not required, you only need them if key is not valid identifier (like has a space or special character in the name).

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iteration througt the array and assembling the objects and push it to the wanted results.

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var array = [{ "_id": 1, "name": "someName", "colorName": "Pink" }, { "_id": 2, "name": "someName2", "colorName": "RoyalBlue" }, { "_id": 3, "name": "aThirdOne", "colorName": "Gold" }, { "_id": 4, "name": "oneMore", "colorName": "LightGreen" }],
    result1 = [],
    result2 = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    result1.push({ value: a._id, label: a.name });
    var o = {};
    o[a._id] = a.name
    result2.push(o);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
var newObject = _.map(yourObject, function(val) {
return {
    "value": val._id,
    "label": val.name
}});
```

And the same concept for the other result you're interested in .